# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "old_column" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I get a very strange error in my tests:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "old_column" violates not-null constraint

E               DETAIL:  Failing row contains (68, , f, , null, f).
```

But "old_column" does not exist in my DB any more.

It was there some hours ago, but this column was renamed to a different name.

If I check the database with `psql mydb` or `manage.py dbshell` and then inspect the db with `\d appname_tablename` then I clearly see that "old_column" does not exist any more.

I have no clue why the DB (PostgreSQL) thinks that this column is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the option "reuse-db", then pytest keeps the test database.

If you use postgres, then you can list the available databases like this:

```
psql -l
                                List of databases
     Name      |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
---------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 postgres      | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 template0     | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
               |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1     | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
               |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres
 test_mydb     | vagrant  | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 mydb          | vagrant  | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
(5 rows)
```

If you connect to "mydb" (via `psql` or `manage.py dbshell`), then this is a different DB then your tests use.

Use [--create-db](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#create-db-force-re-creation-of-the-test-database) to force the re-creation of the DB.